# How to return an exact, pre-set JSON string in PHP?

Tags: php, json

I'm building a mock API that needs to return JSON.

Currently, I am having to turn the JSON into PHP arrays, encode it, then return it.

I want to just return the pre-set JSON that I already have, and also need to accept POST requests.

What's the way to do this?

Comment: `echo $theJsonString;` ?

Comment: Questions seeking help must include *the desired behavior*, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following way:

```
<?php
  $array = (/* The array here... */);
  // Check if it is a POST request.
  if (count($_POST) > 0)
    // Spit out the JSON.
    die(json_encode($array));
  else
    // Exit.
    exit(0);
?>
```

Comment: I don't want to return an array or convert my JSON to PHP arrays - I literally want to return the pure JSON that I already have written.